# PHP usort / uasort Doesn't Sort Multidimensional Array Correctly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pair] => BTCUSDT
            [profit] => 0.2313
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pair] => ETHUSDT
            [profit] => 0.8372
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pair] => NEOUSDT
            [profit] => 0.1832
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pair] => BCCUSDT
            [profit] => 0.4372
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [pair] => XRPUSDT
            [profit] => 0.5372
        )

)
```

and I want to sort that array based on profit number using this code :

```
usort($trading_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['profit'] - $b['profit'];
});
```

but it doesn't produce sorted profit in descending order. in fact, it seems that it randomised my array. here's the result :

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [pair] => XRPUSDT
            [profit] => 0.5372
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pair] => BCCUSDT
            [profit] => 0.4372
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pair] => NEOUSDT
            [profit] => 0.1832
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pair] => ETHUSDT
            [profit] => 0.8372
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [pair] => BTCUSDT
            [profit] => 0.2313
        )

)
```

Comment: usort comparison functions should generally return -1, 0, or 1, to sort properly. Check the examples in the manual and you'll figure it out soon enough: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Note that `return $a['profit']*100 - $b['profit']*100;` works, because the difference must be greater, or lower than 1.

Comment: @Syscall : you're right, bro. it works now! thank you.

Comment: The value returned by the comparison function must be an integer. Your returns small float values that converted to integer produce `0`. And this means all your items are equal.

Comment: @syscall I deleted my previous comment because it was not accurate. Check the new one. The value returned by the comparison function must be an **integer**. Its magnitude doesn't matter.

Comment: OK. Thank you @axiac for the clarification.